# How to read integer value from a list of random inputs?

Tags: python

This program prints a list of words that contains atleast one or more vowels from a list of inputs. If the word does not contain any vowels then it is not read. If the word is an integer then it should print `Strings without vowels:`. So the problem is everytime I input a number it takes in as type `str`. How do I get it as an `int` value from that for loop.

```
def find_Novowels(inp_str):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
    out_list = []
    for word in inp_str:
        count = 0
        if isinstance(word, str):
            for char in word:
                if char in vowels:
                    count += 1
            if count >= 1:
                out_list.append(word)
        else:
            out_list.append('Strings without vowels:')
    return out_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = int(input())
    inp_str = []
    for i in range(count):
        inp_str.append(input())
    print("-----------------------------------")
    output = find_Novowels(inp_str)
    if len(output) != 0:
        for i in output:
            print(i)
    else:
        print('No string found')
```

Output:

```
3
Hello
44
apple
-----------------------------------
Hello 
apple
```

When I give my second input as 44 it reads that value as string. So how can I get it as an integer value or if there is any other simple way to do this please tell me your suggestion.

Comment: You already convert the first input in your program to `int`, why not do the same with the second? I think you need to restate your question, but cause the code shows you know how to convert input to `int` already, so you must need something else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition:

```
if isinstance(word, str):
```

will always be `True` since the `word`s are coming from the source list of strings.

You can do a cast like this: `int(word)` and then catch the exception, but a cleaner way would be to use `isdigit` (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isdigit.asp) and change your condition to:

```
if not word.isdigit():
```